# Could this be explained?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Consider the integer sequence $a(n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ given by

$$a(n) = 10^{n-1}-n$$

The first few terms of this sequence are

$0, 8, 97, 996, 9995, 99994, 999993, 9999992, 99999991, 999999990,
9999999989, 99999999988, 999999999987, 9999999999986$

$${\rm g.f.} = \dfrac{-8x - x^2}{(-1 + x)^2(-1 + 10x)}$$

For $n\ge 3$, the decimal fractional expansion of $1/a(n)$ explicitly reveals some initial powers of $n$, sometimes separated from each other by zeroes.

For example:

$1/97 = 0.0\quad1\quad0\quad3\quad0\quad9\quad27\quad83\quad5051546...$

$1/996 = 0.00\quad1\quad00\quad4\quad0\quad16\quad0\quad64\quad257\quad02811244979919678...$

$1/9995 = 0.000\quad1\quad000\quad5\quad00\quad25\quad0\quad125\quad0\quad625\quad3126\quad5632816...$

How the fact could be explained that in the decimal expansion of the $1/a(n)$ the first initial powers of $n$ are explicitly appearing there and then the very next combination of digits just slightly deviates from the next power of $n$?

P.S. I just found another sequence:

a(n)= (10^(n - 1) - prime(n - 1) +1 )/2

It produces integer values for n >= 3.

n | 1/2 (-p_(n - 1) + 10^(n - 1) + 1)

3 | 49

4 | 498

5 | 4997

6 | 49995

7 | 499994

8 | 4999992

The decimal expansion of 1/a(n) in that sequence (for n >=3) explicitly shows several consecutive occurrences of 2*((prime(n - 1) -1))^k numerical values (possibly separated by zeroes) where the integer "k" starts with the value 0 and then increases incrementally to some integer value "i".

Comment: Interesting query.  Unfortunately, I can not attack it, until you edit it with mathJax to make it more readable, via https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.  I didn't dare attempt this, because I was afraid that I would misinterpret part of your query.

Comment: Perhaps, it is just me, but the "g.f. = (-8x - x^2)/((-1 + x)^2(-1 + 10*x))" seems to come out of left field.  Again, in order to attack the query, I (for one) am going to need a clear idea of what your "g.f..." is supposed to signify.  Re this confusion and the mathJax problem, I can't even question **yet** whether you are asking a direct question, or what that question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sum $0.01 + 0.0003 + 0.000009 + 0.00000027 + \cdots$

This can be rewritten as $1\times 10^{-2} + 3 \times 10^{-4} + 3^2 \times 10^{-6} + \cdots$

which in turn can be condensed as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {3^k}{10^{2(k+1)}}$$

(and/or) by sum of geometric series, this sum equates to

$$\frac {0.01}{1-0.03} = \frac 1{97}$$

Now consider the general situation, which can be expressed as:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {n^k}{10^{(n-1)(k+1)}}$$

which, by sum of geometric series, equates to

$$\frac {1/10^{n-1}}{1-n/10^{n-1}} = \frac {1}{10^{n-1}-n} = \frac 1{a_n}$$

---

Edit in response to the extra question: In general, for $|z|<1$ we have the power series:

$$\frac1{1-z} = 1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots$$

Consider $x_n := p_{n-1}-1$ in your second sequence, $a_n = \dfrac12(10^{n-1}-p_{n-1}+1)$.

We can write:

$$\frac {1}{a_n} = \frac2{10^{n-1}-x_n} = \frac {2/10^{n-1}}{1-x_n/10^{n-1}}=2\times10^{1-n}\left(1+\left(\frac {x_n}{10^{n-1}}\right)+\left(\frac {x_n}{10^{n-1}}\right)^2+\cdots\right)$$

since $x_n < 10^{n-1}$ for $n\ge3$, and in summation form:

$$2\times10^{1-n}\left(1+\left(\frac {x_n}{10^{n-1}}\right)+\left(\frac {x_n}{10^{n-1}}\right)^2+\cdots\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {2x_n^k}{10^{(n-1)(k+1)}}$$

both must therefore show the consecutive occurrences of $2(p_{n - 1} -1)^k$ until the smallest $i \in \mathbb N$ where $2(p_{n-1}-1)^{i+1} > 10^{n-1}$, since carry occurs.

Comment: While what you have written is correct, how it explains the fact that in the decimal expansion of the 1/a(n) the first initial powers of n are appearing and then the very next combination of digits just slightly deviates from the next power of n ?

Comment: I split the decimal expansion $0.01030927...$ into a more concrete form.

Comment: The question has $10^{n-1}-n$, not $10^n-n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fixed, and added more info.